# xml schema nested element within an element with attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I am making a school assignment 
This is my XML

```
<lineup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ComplexTypeDemo.xsd">
  <team teamName="Maple Leafs" city="Toronto">
    <visitor/>
      <player number="17">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <position>Forward</position>
      </player>
      <!--Continue 20 Iterations-->
    </team>
    <team teamName="Rangers" city="New York">
     <home/>
      <player number="17">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <position>Forward</position>
      </player>
      <!--Continue 20 Iterations-->
    </team>
</lineup>
```

here is my schema document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="lineup">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="team" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">

          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>


            <xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="home"/>
              <xs:element name="visitor"/>
            </xs:choice>

              <xs:element name="player" minOccurs="20" maxOccurs="20">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="name" />
                    <xs:element name="position"/>
                  </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>

              </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>


        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

i need to make a schema to validate this. but i can't figure out how to validate  because it is nested but it has attributes. I can only seem to do one or the other, but not both....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.  **You can place attribute declarations after the `xs:sequence` or `xs:all` close tags but before the `xs:complexType` close tag.**  This update to your XSD will validate the XML document instance you provide (modulo actually including 20 iterations as noted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="lineup">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="team" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="home"/>
                <xs:element name="visitor"/>
              </xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="player" minOccurs="20" maxOccurs="20">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="name" />
                    <xs:element name="position"/>
                  </xs:all>
                  <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:integer"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="teamName"/>
            <xs:attribute name="city"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: oh thank you very much. I think i tried every combination of <xs:whatever> but i didn't realize that the attributes need to go at the end of the nested portion.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complex type, you should place the attribute references (or declarations) after your groups (sequences, choices, etc.). For example:

```
<xs:element name="team">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="home"/>
                <xs:element ref="visitor"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="player" minOccurs="20" maxOccurs="20"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="city" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="teamName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If you have a simple type (for example, an empty element which requires an attribute, or one that has string contents), then you should declare your type as a complex type with simple content, and provide an extension of the simple content for your attributes. For example:

```
<xs:element name="visitor">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="visitorName" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Correct too and +1 for also showing xs:simpleContent example.